# How can i use a for each loop to print an Arraylist of different objects of different classes

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, tostring

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Loan loan = new Loan();
        Date date = new Date();
        Strings strings = new Strings();
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        ArrayList<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        mylist.add(loan);
        mylist.add(date);
        mylist.add(strings);
        mylist.add(frame);
        mylist.add(circle);

        for (Object i : mylist)
        {
            System.out.println(mylist.get(i));
        }
         /*
         //this method is working fine
         System.out.println(mylist.get(0));
         System.out.println(mylist.get(1));
         System.out.println(mylist.get(2));
         System.out.println(mylist.get(3));
         System.out.println(mylist.get(4));

         //this method is also working fine
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
            System.out.println(mylist.get(i));
         }*/

    }
}
```

> My Arraylist is of diiferent object types and all have fields with values and a toString method in each class (so that the printing is possible).....If i dont use a loop and if i use an iterating loop its working fine but i want to use a for each loop i used the above syntax but its showing errors.

Comment: `for (Object i : mylist)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
    for (Object i : mylist)
    {
        System.out.println(mylist.get(i));
    }
```

**to**

```
    for (Object i : mylist)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

**`i` in `foreach` loop is the object itself not the index.**

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

and do not declare `myList` as `ArrayList`, but as `List` only - prefer declaring variables as interfaces whenever available

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
for (Object i : mylist)
{
    System.out.println(mylist.get(i)); 
                                  ^----- error here
}
```

You invoke `myList.get()` with an `Object` variable as argument.
It is not valid at compile time as `ArrayList.get()` takes an `int` as parameter :

> `E java.util.ArrayList.get(int index)`

In a some way you mix the foreach and the "basic for" syntax.
The "basic for" statement requires the use of the index :

```
for (int i=0; i<mylist.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(myList.get(i)); 
}
```

But the foreach syntax simplifies that :

```
for (Object i : mylist) {
     System.out.println(i); 
}
```